# What's a good reason to use RegEx constructor properties' short names in lieu of the verbose names?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am studying JavaScript (using *Professional Javascript for Web Developers*[1]), and I was wondering why a developer might use the short names in RegExp rather than the more semantically meaningful verbose names (i.e. "$_" instead of input or "$`" instead of leftContext)?

In the time it would take me to look up the short name (or even, I assume, with code completion), I could easily type the verbose names. However, I don't want to blow them off if they are important, so why might a programmer prefer the short names?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Some context. In the book the following example is given:

```
var text = "this has been a short summer"; 
var pattern = /(.)hort/g; 

 if (pattern.test( text)){ 

   alert( RegExp.input);                     // this has been a short summer 
   alert( RegExp.$_);                        // this has been a short summer 

   alert( RegExp.leftContext);               // this has been a 
   alert( RegExp.["$`"]);                    // this has been a 

   alert( RegExp.rightContext);              // summer 
   alert( RegExp.["$'"]);                    // summer 

   alert( RegExp.lastMatch);                 // short 
   alert( RegExp.["$&"]);                    // short 

   alert( RegExp.lastParen);                 // s 
   alert( RegExp.["$+"]);                    // s 

  }
```

If even these verbose forms are deprecated, then I imagine my question would slightly different ("How might you accomplish these tasks without them?").

1: Zakas, Nicholas C. (2011-12-20). Professional JavaScript for Web Developers. John Wiley and Sons.

Comment: Looks like they are all deprecated - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features . Can you provide some textual examples of exactly what you see or are using?

Comment: Deprecated huh? Maybe I should drop the publishers a note. Added some more context above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `` RegExp.["$`"] `` and `RegExp.["$'"]` are aleady "dead", and `RegExp.$+` and `RegExp.$&` behave unexpectedly.

Current (April 30, 2015) output:

**RegExp.input**: this has been a short summer
**RegExp.$_**: this has been a short summer
**RegExp.leftContext**: this has been a 
**RegExp.rightContext**: summer
**RegExp.lastMatch**: short
0
**RegExp.lastParen**: s
**RegExp.$+**: undefinedNaN

Here is a live test:

```js
var text = "this has been a short summer"; 
var pattern = /(.)hort/g; 



 if (pattern.exec(text) != null) {

   document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += "<b>RegExp.input</b>: " + RegExp.input + "<br />";               // this has been a short summer 
   document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += "<b>RegExp.$_</b>: " + RegExp.$_ + "<br />";                  // this has been a short summer 
   
   document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += "<b>RegExp.leftContext</b>: " + RegExp.leftContext + "<br />";       // this has been a 
   //document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += RegExp.["$`"] + "<br />";            // this has been a, now, does not let compile

   document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += "<b>RegExp.rightContext</b>: " + RegExp.rightContext + "<br />";    // summer 
   //document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += RegExp.["$'"] + "<br />";           // summer, now, does not let compile

   document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += "<b>RegExp.lastMatch</b>: " + RegExp.lastMatch + "<br />";           // short 
   document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += "<b>RegExp.$&</b>: " + RegExp.$& + "<br />";                  // was "short", now, evaluates the expression on the right to 0

   document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += "<br /><b>RegExp.lastParen</b>: " + RegExp.lastParen + "<br />";          // s 
   document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += "<b>RegExp.$+</b>: " + RegExp.$+ + "<br />";                 // was "s", now, outputs "NaN"

  }
```

```html
<div id="res" />
```

Answer (score 0):

They have the previous patterns as I believed that's what they are in other languages (such as Perl), so there would be that familiarity if your background was with a different language.

They should only be used in replacement strings, such as `"ABC".replace(/[ABC]/g, "$&")`.

Comment: `s/They are also used in/They should only be used in/` :)

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase the Perl [Camel book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_Perl), there are situations where you want to emphasize "quick and dirty" and save development time, and situations where you want to emphasize maintainability.  If you just need a quick hack to get the job done, then whatever you manage to remember without looking it up is faster than the nice, human-readable, self-documenting code you would normally want to write.  To paraphrase a [different adage](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast), for a first prototype you intend to come back and polish once you can get the basic flow working, you want to "make it work" before you put any effort into "make it right".

(This reasoning is, of course, prone to come back and bite your behind, but nevertheless this is the reasoning.)